# JS with multiple buttons/functions for AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a generic block for making POST REST calls as below, want to know whats the most effective way to having multiple of these blocks in a single file(multiple buttons with associated functions)? Can I have a request factory type of thing?

```
    <button>somewhere</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.post("/somewheregood/",
            JSON.stringify(
            {
              some: "where"
            }),
            function(data,status){
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: So you somehow have to specify what data goes with it, most people would use data attributes.

Comment: You can also use the `value` attribute, and `$(this).val()` in the click handler.